# Model-View-Presenter: Why is model static?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been attempting to fully understand the Model View Presenter pattern as it applies to C#.  I have one question I can't wrap my head around.

In many examples, I noticed that model is defined as static and is constructed in the Presenter base class (often a generic class).

How does one have multiple model classes in that case? From my understanding, every presenter created will only be able to reference a single model class.

The example I'm looking at now can be found here: http://wesaday.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/finalzip.doc (rename to .zip). It's from this tutorial: http://wesaday.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/winform-model-view-presenter-part-v-the-view/

The guess the overall issue I'm having is seeing how examples like the one above adapt to a working application with multiple views/presenters/models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is presumably just a simplification in order to avoid incorporating a complete IoC implementation in the sample.  An MVP triad is usually represented by stand-alone (i.e.: not static, singleton, or otherwise shared) instances at runtime.  In some exceptional cases, a model may be a shared instance, but this is usually the exception rather than the rule, and it's generally only the case for read-only forms or controls.

Comment: I think I understand. Does this mean that the presenter class should always instantiate a model class (since its not a shared instance)?

Comment: The presenter should either instantiate a new model instance or receive it from an external source.  For example, I usually add an Initialize(model, view) method to my base presenter, then apply logic based on the model value to determine how to instantiate the model. If the value is null, an abstract method is invoked to allow the subclass to create a new model instance.  If the value corresponds to the type of the model, the presenter simply uses it as its model. If the value corresponds to the type of the model's ID, the ID value gets passed to an abstract method for retrieval of the model.